# DNN Error after creating a module

Tags: dotnetnuke

I was given a project for maintenance, it is built on `DNN 9.1.1` and has some custom modules (I am completely new to `DNN`). I needed to create a new module, so I used the christoc project templates for `VS2017`. So even before I could develop anything, I rebuilt the solution and it gave me a `DNN` Error. I removed the project from the solution, but while it compiles correctly, it still gives the same error.

**Has anyone ever got this error? Do you think the module are being written to the database and if so, how can I delete it?**

I'm posting the errors in the log but it doesn't make sense to me, because no files are missing

> DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: Unhandled error loading page. ---> System.Web.HttpParseException: The file '/DesktopModules/GFIPortugal/DotNetNuke.Search.Google/GoogleSearch.ascx' does not exist. ---> System.Web.HttpParseException: The file '/DesktopModules/GFIPortugal/DotNetNuke.Search.Google/GoogleSearch.ascx' does not exist. ---> System.Web.HttpException: The file '/DesktopModules/GFIPortugal/DotNetNuke.Search.Google/GoogleSearch.ascx' does not exist.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that this is a common error. Funny how it was so hard to find on google. I leave the link here https://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/12, and urge everyone with template errors to refer to this site.

In plain, the solution is this:

1. Load the IIS Manager (start>run>inetmgr.exe)
2. Expand the Tree view on the left side of the screen until you see the SITES folder
3. Expand the Sites folder until you find your development site
4. Expand your development site (DNNDEV.ME) until you see the DesktopModules folder
5. If the DesktopModules folder has an "arrow" on it, IIS thinks it is a virtual directory, and this is what causes the error above. Right click on the DesktopModules folder, choose Delete.
6. Reload the site in your web browser, and the error should go away. Do not simply refresh the browser, as the error is in the URL and will likely just reload the error page even though you've fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

Does the .`ascx` control exist in the correct path?

```
'/DesktopModules/GFIPortugal/DotNetNuke.Search.Google/GoogleSearch.ascx'
```

Maybe you have created an extra subfolder.
try like this:

```
'/DesktopModules/GFIPortugal/GoogleSearch.ascx'
```

When you add a new module via Visual Studio unselect the option to create a folder for your project/solution (bottom right of the Add New Project wizard).
Also, check the .`dnn` file to adjust the mappings of your resources.